# How to disable CBC-mode ciphers

Tags: openssl, cipher-selection

Is there a simple allowlist-style way of disabling CBC mode cipher suites in apps that use an openssl cipher suite list? I'm hoping for something in the style of `!RC4`, however, `!CBC` has no effect, and still allows suites such as `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`.

The only solution I've found so far is to use a much more verbose allowlist that only includes non-CBC ciphers. Is there a simpler alternative?

Comment: Isn't there very very little left if you exclude CBC and non forward secure and limit to AES ciphers? I think all that's left then is like four (?) GCM ciphers, right? And you could well put that as a whitelist?

Comment: Yes, it's true, it does end up being quite a short whitelist! Don't forget ChaCha20 though...

Comment: Today, the easiest way to disable CBC cipher suites would be to only allow TLS in version 1.3 or above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the list of Cipher Strings given in [the documentation (man ciphers)](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ciphers.html) there is no string describing all CBC ciphers. This means there is no simple way to disable all of these (and only these) with a simple `!CBC` or similar.

Answer (score 35):

You can use `!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384` to disable all CBC mode ciphers. There are some non-CBC false positives that will also be disabled (`RC4`, `NULL`), but you probably also want to disable them anyway.

Note that while `GCM` and `CHACHA20` ciphers have `SHA*` in their name, they're not disabled because they use their own MAC algorithm. The `SHA*` in their name is for [the PRF, not the MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26410/whats-the-gcm-sha-256-of-a-tls-protocol/26434#26434)

Comment: This is necessary especially since CBC algorithms are now rated as weak.

Comment: @imgx64 in which file and location in Nginx web server should I apply this?

Answer (score 15):

I've spent a fair amount of time over the last couple of days trying to get a perfect list for ssllabs.  Thanks in part to this, here's what works:

```
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!RSA:!CAMELLIA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS:!RC4:!SHA1:!SHA256:!SHA384
```

Comment: This accomplishes A+ by disabling the four CBC mode equivalent ciphers and leaving four GCM. I use it and have received no adverse feedback. Qualys shows that all except a range of older devices and browsers are happy with this, but if you serve a wider range of clients, you may need to be more lenient and use something like `SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH`.

Comment: This list still contains CBC ciphers: verify this with 

```openssl ciphers -V -stdname EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH | grep CBC
```

Answer (score 3):

The best SSL Ciphers and Protocols settings I found at https://cipherli.st/

With this you will get a Qualys A+ rating:

```
SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM
# Requires Apache 2.4.36 & OpenSSL 1.1.1
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3 +TLSv1.2
```

Comment: This is a whitelist, which I've already got - the question asks if there is a *blacklist* to disable all CBC-mode cipher suites. Also there is no such thing as a "best" cipher suite list, as it's very dependent on your prospective audience.

Comment: Although @Synchro is formally correct ... after testing different variants in Qualys SSL Labs (not believing that a good solution could be as easy), I came to the conclusion that this has about exactly the same browser/OS coverage like more complex solutions, combined from black- and whitelists.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this directly, however you can script it a bit.

Let's say that your initial cipher suites string is `!3DES:HIGH`. (You should probably have a better cipher suites string to begin with, but that's a good starting point and won't clutter this answer too much.)

Now, do this:

```
$ openssl ciphers '!3DES:HIGH' \
    | sed -e 's/:/\n/g' \
    | grep -v GCM \
    | sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/:!/g' -e 's/^/!/'
```

Explanation, per line:

1. Start with the set of ciphers you "really" want
2. Split the `:`-separated list into one-per-line cipher suite
3. Remove anything that doesn't explicitly say `GCM`
4. Read the whole file in at once, replace newlines with `:!`, then add a `!` at the very beginning

Now take this output and place it at the front of your cipher suite string. Don't throw-out your original, because you might want to re-run this process later when your initial cipher suites string changes, or if new ciphers are added to OpenSSL or even to their `HIGH` default list.